pdfpages Error with subfiles and XeLaTeX
I have a project with the following structure:
./sections/appendices/appendices.tex
./sections/appendices/my_file.pdf
main.tex

Here's a MWE:
main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\subfile{sections/appendices/appendices}
\end{document}

appendices.tex
\documentclass[../../main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering  
    \includepdf{\subfix{my_file.pdf}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

When I compile from appendices.tex, there is no problem.
When I compile from main.tex, everything compiles, the pdf file displays as it should (even after clearing cache) but XeLaTeX throws me:
Package pdfpages Error: Page 1 of `sections/appendices/my_file.pdf' does not exist.
See the pdfpages package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7     \includepdf{\subfix{my_file.pdf}}
                                         
You have set a wrong page number in the `pages' option. Document 
`sections/appendices/my_file.pdf' does not have 1 pages.

The problem does not appear when compiling with LuaLaTeX or pdfLaTeX so I think it's not a problem with my pdf file.
Still, you can find it here.

well the internal command of pdfpages that counts the pages of the PDF with xelatex does not like the \subfix command. Why do you use that? It seems to compile without it.

Yes, I can confirm this bug. Thank you for the report and the very good MWE.
I've fixed the bug and a new version of pdfpages is on its way to CTAN already. It should be available there in one or two days.
If you need it earlier, just drop me a mail.
